# Bulk Edit for Custom post in WP

Tags: wordpress, inline, custom-post-type

Is there any way to make a separate *`inline_edit()`* or we can say override function for a custom post type.
This function is defined in class **'WP_Posts_List_Table'** which is in file `'wp_admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php'` . I don't want to edit core files of WP.

Comment: You want to do Bulk inline edit?

Comment: @BhumiShah Yes I want to a separate screen for my custom bulk action which needs to be inline